# Swing application hanging while ClassLoader load libawt_lwawt.dylib

Tags: java, macos, swing

My swing frames freeze before opening.

The application hangs while loading a class that extends JFrame, but does not execute the first constructor instruction :

```
app = new MyFrame(); // debug reach this point

public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    public MyFrame(){
        super(); // debug don't reach this point
        ...
    }
}
```

When pausing the thread from eclipse, I see java.lang.ClassLoader is trying to load :

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libawt_lwawt.dylib

The weird thing is that some of my applications can run swing UI using the same JDK.

The application hangs both when started from eclipse or from command line

Dev Config

- MacOS 10.8.5
- JavaSE 1.8 execution environement with JDK 1.8.0-20

From command line I have :

```
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

To create a JFrame:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DemoJFrame extends JFrame {

    public DemoJFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DemoJFrame().setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is not a question of how to write code to open JFrame, but a problem loading the JFrame in itself. The example code I gave was just to clarify where the program hangs.